# Unable to connect to Interbase 2020 Database with PHP 8.2

Tags: php, interbase

We recently installed Interbase Server 2020 on Windows Server 2019
with Apache Server 2.4.57 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.2 PHP/8.2.10

I am able to connect to the Interbase SQL Database remotely with  IBConsole Administrator Database Utility on port 3050.

The following link show the php info
including the interbase extension:

http://70.182.48.236/testphp.php

I am not able to connect to the Interbase SQL Database remotely with PHP 8.2.

```
$db = ibase_connect( DB_HOST.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 'ISO8859_1', 100, 1) OR die('Unable to connect to the loan servicing database. ');
```

I receive the following error:

> Warning: ibase_connect(): connection rejected by remote interface in
> C:\Program Files\Apache2\htdocs\test-sqlconnect.php on line 24

What can I do to connect to the Interbase 2020 Database remotely with PHP 8.2?

Comment: `DB_HOST.DB_NAME` shoudn't it be a comma?

Comment: It should be `ibase_connect( DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 'ISO8859_1', 100, 1)`

Comment: ibase_connect — Open a connection to a database

Format:
ibase_connect(
    string $database = ?,
    string $username = ?,
    string $password = ?,
    string $charset = ?,
    int $buffers = ?,
    int $dialect = ?,
    string $role = ?,
    int $sync = ?
);The database argument has to be a valid path to database file on the server it resides on. If the server is not local, it must be prefixed with either 'hostname:' (TCP/IP), 'hostname/port:' (TCP/IP with interbase server on custom TCP port), '//hostname/' (NetBEUI), depending on the connection protocol used.

Comment: <?php  # Script test-sqlconnect.php###



DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'Administrator');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'Password!');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '70.182.48.236:');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'c:\twenty-first century\Loan Servicing System\LOANS.GDB');



$db      =  ibase_connect( DB_HOST.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 'ISO8859_1', 100, 1) OR die('Unable to connect to the loan servicing database. ');

?>